# Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent

Tags: php, mysql, session

Error al intentar ingresar me explico en localhost funciona bien pero al momento de subirlo a algun servidor marca este error

```
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /storage/ssd3/893/822893/public_html/index.php:33) in /storage/ssd3/893/822893/public_html/php/login.php on line 11

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /storage/ssd3/893/822893/public_html/index.php:33) in /storage/ssd3/893/822893/public_html/php/login.php on line 11

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /storage/ssd3/893/822893/public_html/index.php:33) in /storage/ssd3/893/822893/public_html/php/login.php on line 15
```

mire por hay que session_start deberia estar en el inicio despues de la etiqueta `<?php`

```
<?php
session_start();
```

pero sigue igual tambien mire que era por los espacios en blanco bueno junte las lineas sin dejar renglones y sigue igual

aca esta mi codigo original

```
<?php



    $correo=$_POST['correo'];
    $clave=md5($_POST['clave']);
    require_once('Conexion.php');
    $conn = Conectar();

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT  id_usuario, nombre, apellido, correo, p.id_perfil, perfil FROM usuario u INNER JOIN perfil p ON p.id_perfil=u.id_perfil WHERE u.correo=:correo AND u.clave=:clave");
    $stmt->bindParam(':correo',$correo);
    $stmt->bindParam(':clave',$clave);
    $stmt->execute();



    if($stmt->rowCount()==1){
        session_start();
        $fila=$stmt->fetch();
        $_SESSION['idperfil']=$fila['id_perfil'];
        if($fila['id_perfil']==1)
            {header("Location: administrador/index.php");}
        if($fila['id_perfil']==2)
            {header("Location: aprendiz/index.php");}
        if($fila['id_perfil']==3)
            {header("Location: root/index.php");}
    }
    else{
         echo "<font color='red'>Datos No Validos</font>";
    }
?>
```

espero que me puedan ayudar y gracias

Comment: perdonen puse despues de la etiqueta pero no me cogio la etiqueta es <?php

Comment: `session_start();` debe estar al principio del código, no dentro del `if` como lo tienes ahora y no debe haber ningún tipo de salida o código HTML antes.

Comment: Puedes revisar que los `headers` ya fueron enviados en cualquier parte de tu código con: `if (headers_sent()) { echo "Oh no!"; }`

Answer (score 3):

Según la [documentación de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php):

> Para usar sesiones basadas en cookies, `session_start()` debe ser
>   llamada antes de imprimir cualquier cosa en el navegador.

Debes controlar que no haya absolutamente ningún tipo de salida (`echo, print...`) o de código HTML antes de `session_start();`

Y eso no es solo referente al script en cuestión, sino que debes tomarlo en cuenta muy especialmente cuando concatenas archivos mediante `include` o `require`. El mensaje de error indica que están interviniendo los archivos `login.php`  e `index.php`. Si por ejemplo tú incluyes código HTML en `login.php` o sacas algo por pantalla y luego usas `session_start()` en `index.php` vas a tener este tipo de errores.

Answer (score 0):

Es muy sencillo, solo cierra *PHP* y después de la orden y después lo vuelves a abrir para continuar tu código:

```
<?php session_start() ?>
```

... y vuelves a abrir *PHP* y continúas el resto del código:

Answer (score 0):

El problema consiste en que esta llamando a `session_start()` tanto en el archivo `login.php` cuando ya lo haz declarado en `index.php`.

Para solucionar tu problema debes **validar primero si se debe ejecutar `session_start`**, tomado el [estado de la sesión en php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php), con esta linea de código lo puedes hacer:

```php
if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {session_start();}
```

Ahora si esta usando php menor a **5.4** puedes usar esto:

```php
if(session_id() == '') { session_start(); }
```

## Recomendación:

Ya que estas creando un sistema de *login*, no es recomendable implementar `session_start` en `login.php` , ni tampoco en `index.php`, simplemente redirige a tu publico a otra pagina como por ejemplo `home.php`. Puedes verificar si el usuario esta logeado en `index.php` y direccionar con el siguiente [código](https://entredesarrolladores.com/12665/como-validar-sesi%C3%B3n-iniciada-en-php).

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
    session_start(); 
    switch ($_SESSION['idperfil']) {
      case 1:
        header("Location: administrador/index.php");
        break;
      case 2:
        header("Location: aprendiz/index.php");
        break;
      case 3:
        header("Location: root/index.php");
        break;
} 
else {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit;
}
?>
```